# Should answers be tailored to the level of the OP's question?

Tags: discussion

Every now and then, one comes across a question that clearly shows that the level of the OP's coding skills is at best beginner, if not novice and yet the answers provided are set at a level way above that.
Should we attempt to take their skill level into consideration, when answering the question?
 A high skill level answer might well indeed answer the problem but does it help the OP?
I know that there will be some of the view that it might well extend the knowledge of the Original Poster but there are answers out there that are really way beyond the level of the poster.
I take the view, that an attempt should be made to tailor the answer to the level of the poster, even if that means that you cannot dazzle others with your skills.

Comment: If I was the OP I would be happy to learn something new, so my guess is - No, don't write an answer that match the level of the OP (Who knows, they might be intelligent enough to understand a more  complex solution). I might downvote an answer even if it's correct, but is demonstrating a bad practice. I expect that answers should improve the OP skills

Comment: Similar question but for "documentation": [What level of experience should we assume for readers of SO Documentation?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332266)

Comment: @Tom With the greatest of respect, I disagree on both counts. I am asking whether we should take a proactive stance concerning the nature of the answer, when faced with a question which  is `clearly` at a beginner's level.

Comment: As explained in the dupes answer: you're not only answering the question for OP only, thus the answer to the question *"Should we attempt to take their skill level into consideration, when answering the question?"* is: not when this would mean that you reduce the quality of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think we're even going to agree on what "tailoring an answer to the OP's skill level" means. Some people will think any explanation will go over a beginner's head while others think a beginner should get more explanation than not.

But answers are ultimately meant to be useful to the community as a whole. That doesn't mean it has to somehow be at the expense of the OP but it's important to keep in mind that you aren't just answering the question for them.

I think it's unfair to assume that someone posting an answer that wasn't written the way you would have had malicious intent:

> even if that means that you cannot dazzle others with your skills

If your answer would vary that drastically from what you would have said, you are always free to leave your own answer.

Comment: At no point did I suggest there was ever "malicious intent". I knew that this could be contentious but if one takes the view that the answer has to benefit the community as a whole, one also has to take into account that the community includes novices as well. Indeed, I am lower than a novice in many categories. I'm simply postulating that if it is a novice question, shouldn't we may an effort to provide an answer, that is not only correct and informative but that also does not fly straight over their head. I take your point about leaving a simpler answer.

Comment: The "dazzle" remark did not infer malicious intent. It was no more than a  reference to the all too human trait of demonstrating our skills for others to see, whether it is appropriate or not. Something that we are all guilty of at some time or other.

Answer (score 3):

When I answer a question that appears to be written by a beginner, I don't write code that is any different for anyone else, but I try to dissect my answer more than usual.

For example, if I use a series of common table expressions, or do something a little more advanced, I try to talk about why I did those steps and what the intermediate output would look like. My intent is to help them visualize what the code is doing at each step so they can understand why I did it.

I also tend to explain more best practices, such as fully qualifying fields in a SELECT query, good naming conventions, effective use of white space, etc. I don't do that with more advanced questions. There I might provide the code and a quick snippet about the single part that made it work and what was causing their problem.